# Change tmux key-binding for bash script

Tags: tmux

We do have a bash script, which we can run on a cluster access node, that executes htop on all cluster child nodes, in order for us to monitor the whole cluster at once.

Now my question is, whether, there is a way to bind `Ctrl-C` or `q` for this script, without having to use the tmux prefix. The idea is, that this would make the script behave very similar to the regular htop command (which uses the q key binding to quit), and other users would not have to dive into the specifics of how to use tmux, when wanting to quit the window.

I am aware, that there is a way to change the behaviour using the `.tmux.conf` file. However, we do not want to set these keybinding globally, but only for this single script.

The command bash script looks like this:

```
tmux new -s logs_htop -d ssh-run htop 1
tmux select-pane -T 'cn01'

tmux splitw -v -p 50 -t logs_htop:0.0 ssh-run htop 5
tmux select-pane -T 'cn05'

tmux splitw -h -p 75 -t logs_htop:0.0 ssh-run htop 2
tmux select-pane -T 'cn02'

tmux splitw -h -p 66 -t logs_htop:0.1 ssh-run htop 3
tmux select-pane -T 'cn03'

tmux splitw -h -p 50 -t logs_htop:0.2 ssh-run htop 4
tmux select-pane -T 'cn04'

tmux splitw -h -p 75 -t logs_htop:0.4 ssh-run htop 6
tmux select-pane -T 'cn06'

tmux splitw -h -p 66 -t logs_htop:0.5 ssh-run htop 7
tmux select-pane -T 'cn07'

tmux splitw -h -p 50 -t logs_htop:0.6 "watch squeue -al"
tmux select-pane -T 'squeue'

tmux attach -t logs_htop
```

Comment: How would this script use `C-c` as a tmux bind? Why do you want a script to be able to use a keybind?

Comment: There is no need for a "classic" tmux key-binding, as I do not need any other tmux functionality, other than splitting the screen and running htop on the different cluster nodes. Basically, once the above script has been executed and is showing the different htops, I want an easy and "intuitive" way to kill the whole session. Such that users can either hit `Ctrl-C` or `q` to exist the while session. Since this is the behaviour they would expect when executing the regular htop command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by connecting to a different tmux socket with a custom tmux config file.

First, create your custom tmux keybind in a separate conf file:

```
mkdir -p /etc/tmux
echo "bind-key -n C-c kill-session" > /etc/tmux/tmux-logs-htop.conf
# do not recommend q as htop is context-sensitive and q does not *always* mean quit
echo "bind-key -n q kill-session" >> /etc/tmux/tmux-logs-htop.conf
```

Next, create your custom tmux server:

```
tmux -L logs_htop -f /etc/tmux/tmux-logs-htop.conf
```

Lastly, edit your script to prefix every command with the particular socket / tmux server the commands are going to:

```
tmux -L logs_htop new -s logs_htop -d ssh-run htop 1 
...
```

---

From `man tmux`:

```
-L socket-name
 tmux stores the server socket in a directory under TMUX_TMPDIR or /tmp if it is unset.
 The default socket is named default.  This option allows a different socket name to be
 specified, allowing several independent tmux servers to be run.  Unlike -S a full path is
 not necessary: the sockets are all created in the same directory.
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Just one more thing. When I put all of this into a single script, including my script, then it first opens up a tmux console, with the new server, which I have to detach manually, and it proceeds with the rest of my above script. If I add a `-d` flag to your command: `tmux -L logs_htop -f /etc/tmux/tmux-logs-htop.conf -d`, then the key bind dings do not work anymore. Is there any workaround, which makes it possible to put this all in a single script?

Comment: Did you try to "edit your script to prefix every command with the particular socket" ?

Comment: I found the problem. I had an extra `tmux -L logs_htop kill-session -t logs_htop` in there, where the original idea was to kill the session, if some user detached it. Because previously running the script, detaching and running it again, nested the script within the first open tmux session. However, here I do not need the kill-session anymore.
Thank you again for the great advice!